# Truncate followed by Insert in one transaction MySQL

Tags: mysql, transactions

I have a database with frequently changing raw data. 
There is a pretty complex process that creates a summary table of this data.

I've created a Stored Procedure to create this table which uses a sequence of three tables. As I don't yet track what data has been updated (I'm working on that) I simply populate these queries with a sequence of:

```
TRUNCATE tablename ...
INSERT INTO tablename ...
```

I have moved all of these three queries into a single transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION READ WRITE;

  [Sequence of TRUNCATE / INSERT queries]

COMMIT;
```

I expected that after the commit I would immediately see the resulting table but there seems to be a 2-3 second period where the table is empty. Is there a simple way to fix this?

Comment: What is the context in which you see this delay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NO!! ,
you cant use **TRUNCATE** in a transaction. **Truncate** deletes the hole Table File an re-creates it . **Truncate operations cause an implicit commit.**

**a idea:**

It can be work with RENAME. Rename is a single transaction

```
CREATE TABLE table_copy like your_table;
INSERT DATA in table_copy;
RENAME your_table TO your_table_old, table_copy TO your_table;
DROP table_copy;
```

Comment: @Hans - i have add some stuff

Comment: Ah okay no point me reading and rereading about transactions if the problem sit's with the commands used therein. Thank you that solved it.

Comment: Actually would it then not be better to just DELETE all rows?

Comment: @Hans - delete works for each row. So it can be take a long time if your table has many rows. DELETE also updates the INDEX and DELETE not resets AUTO_INCREMENTS. How many rows has your table ? how many rows you are insert ? and which engine you are using ?

Comment: I'm using InnoDB for the source tables. This target table is simply a Memory table.